# SQL Database Query Performance Chart on Large Datasets?

Tags: sql, nosql

What are the best docs/articles out there that show how different queries perform on large data sets?  I'm trying to get a feel approaches are better than others in building a dashboard where the number and type of queries easily becomes large and complex, and slow.

Comment: What do you mean with "different queries"? Are you trying to decide on query syntax, or are you trying to decide on which database to use for your needs?

Comment: I think all of it.  He's trying to see NoSQL vs a distributed sql vs singletable vs multitable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you take the time to get a book on performance tuning for the database backend you are using. Performance tuning is very database specific and techiniques that are fast on one database may be dog slow on another (Cursors on Oracle and SQL Server comes to mind). If you are going to be writing complex queries, you need to understand performance tuning in depth before trying to write them. I will give you a hint - joins are usually faster than correlated subqueries whcih developers often use becasue they seem more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to compare the actual performance of one database architecture over another, I think the most common you'll find are benchmarks, which will vary, or theoretical proposals.

It's certainly harder to compare SQL vs NoSQL because you need a lot of data in the first place to have NoSQL be beneficial.

Minimizing joins, indexing properly, and having enough memory/cpu availability are going to be the three dominating factors.